# Does setTimeOut function in Jquery works with Jquery.fn.extend({ });

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one div element

```
  <div id="progressbar1"></div>
```

then through jquery I am declaring one function

```
$(function() {
    $("#progressbar1").increment({target:200});
});

jQuery.fn.extend({
    increment:function(obj){
        console.log($(this).children().attr("value-now"));
        var current_val=$(this).children().attr("value-now");
        var max_val=obj.target||$(this).children().attr("value-max");
        if(current_val<max_val)
        {
            current_val++;
            var widthp=current_val/max_val;
            widthp=widthp*100;
            $(this).children().width(widthp.toFixed(0)+"%");
            setTimeout(increment,100);
        }
    }
});
```

But with SetTimeout function error is coming function increment is not defined.If I remove setTimeout increment is working fine.So I want to know whether Jquery.fn.extend works with setTimeout or not??

Comment: Your object in anonymous. Normally you would refer to `window` or some other object you attach your properties to.

Answer (score 1):

As `setTimeout` is just JavaScript, and jQuery is also just JavaScript, yes you can use it in a jQ method.

You are referencing something named `increment` as the function to run in your `setTimeout` line. You have not, however, defined any such function named `increment`.

`increment` is a method you've defined on the jQuery prototype, so replace your `setTimeout` line with this:

```
var $this = $(this);
setTimeout(function () {
    $this.increment(obj);
}, 100);
```

Here's a full version of your code with some cleanup (untested):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    increment: function (obj) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                children = $this.children(),
                current_val = children.attr('value-now'),
                max_val = obj.target || children.attr('value-max'),
                widthp;

            if (current_val < max_val) {
                current_val++;
                // you'll probably want to update `children.attr('value-now')` here
                widthp = (current_val / max_val) * 100;
                children.width(widthp.toFixed(0) + '%');

                setTimeout(function () {
                    $this.increment(obj);
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
});

$(function() {
    $("#progressbar1").increment({target:200});
});
```

Comment: It worked fine.Yahh I realized it I was not associating increment method with object by your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Right now `increment` is not defined anywhere. What you need is to call `$.fn.increment` method. One more approach to do it properly is using [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/):

```
setTimeout($.proxy(this.increment, this), 100);
```